# Fill empty columns with the number that occurred before in Python

Tags: python, pandas

```
df= df.pivot(index='user', columns= 'slot', values='location')
```

NaN should be replaced with the value before that. If there is no value in the beginning then it should replce with the first value that comes in the row.

```
slot     1      2       3       4        5
User    
1      NaN     456     NaN     NaN      76  
2      46      NaN     NaN     657      63
4      NaN     NaN     NaN     79       123
5      NaN     782     NaN     451      NaN
6      NaN     NaN     452     897      NaN
8      NaN     686     NaN     NaN      NaN
```

```
slot     1      2       3       4        5
User    
1      456     456     456     456      76  
2      46      46      46      657      63
4      79      79      79      79       123
5      782     782     782     451      451
6      452     452     452     897      897
8      686     686     686     686      686
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can just [`ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) and [`bfill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) over `axis=1`

```
df.ffill(axis=1).bfill(axis=1)
```

---

```
       1      2      3      4      5
0  456.0  456.0  456.0  456.0   76.0
1   46.0   46.0   46.0  657.0   63.0
2   79.0   79.0   79.0   79.0  123.0
3  782.0  782.0  782.0  451.0  451.0
4  452.0  452.0  452.0  897.0  897.0
5  686.0  686.0  686.0  686.0  686.0
```